# How can I link a composer lib to a local source?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

The case is that I have a main project using a composer lib made by someone on my team, and I don't have write access in this lib repository, so any change done in this lib needs to be commited, pull requested and published to be updated in the main project (by composer update).

Is there some way to link this lib folder on my main project, to my locally forked source, so I can use my own changes skiping this whole proccess?

**P.S.** I can't change the source on `composer.json`. It would be good if we can overwrite some items in composer using like as `composer-custom.json` as we can do in the Vagrant settings.

Comment: Symlink the folder? Or declare custom repo for this package at global Composer config level if that's possible (instead of local `composer.json`)? Nothing to do with PhpStorm anyway.

Comment: diging into our idea about composer global config, i've found this composer issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/601 thx anyway! And about the symlink, if I composer update and there is any new version for this lib, it will overide it.